# Server-Side-Pagination Kendo Grid with Angular 6 - Paginator always resets to 1st Page

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am using `Kendo Grid ~3.6.0` with `Angular 6`

I have completed all the functionality of Server Side Pagination except one thing.

Whenever I click some page number or arrow keys, it gets the data related to that page but it always resets to highlighting of page number to `1` instead of current page and status of page is always showing as `1-20 of 2000 items` where 2000 is the total number of rows in the Grid.

Bascially, it is resetting the pagenumber to `1`.

Even I have implemented `DataStateChange` event also as below

```
public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    this.userService.startIndex = state.skip;
    this.userService.endIndex = state.skip + this.messagesPerPage;
    this.loadItems();
}
```

How can I make it function properly in Navigating the pages?

Comment: Is there anyone to figure it out please?

Comment: what is template?

Comment: Currently it is working fine. I am using dataStateChange event twice. Once it is removed it is working perfectly.